# Azure Mobile App OData query adds extra columns killing SQL performance

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

We have an Azure Mobile App with a rather large SQL Azure database behind it. (Around 8 GB) (It's large for a mobile app)

The example I'm giving is an address table with around 286k rows.

The query EntityFramework generates is the following:

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 DATETIMEOFFSET = '2017-07-07'

SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    N'c9e6eec9-46f2-4aa4-901d-d380b9cf3e4b' AS [C2], 
    N'Deleted' AS [C3], 
    [Extent1].[Deleted] AS [Deleted], 
    N'UpdatedAt' AS [C4], 
    [Extent1].[UpdatedAt] AS [UpdatedAt], 
    N'CreatedAt' AS [C5], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
    N'Version' AS [C6], 
    [Extent1].[Version] AS [Version], 
    N'Id' AS [C7], 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    N'ValidUntil' AS [C8], 
    [Extent1].[ValidUntil] AS [ValidUntil], 
    N'ValidFrom' AS [C9], 
    [Extent1].[ValidFrom] AS [ValidFrom], 
    N'ZipCode' AS [C10], 
    [Extent1].[ZipCode] AS [ZipCode], 
    N'DistrictId' AS [C11], 
    [Extent1].[DistrictId] AS [DistrictId], 
    N'Label' AS [C12], 
    [Extent1].[Label] AS [Label], 
    N'TownName' AS [C13], 
    [Extent1].[TownName] AS [TownName], 
   N'StreetName' AS [C14], 
    [Extent1].[StreetName] AS [StreetName], 
   N'TownId' AS [C15], 
    [Extent1].[TownId] AS [TownId], 
    N'StreetId' AS [C16], 
    [Extent1].[StreetId] AS [StreetId]
    FROM [dbo].[Address] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[UpdatedAt] > @p__linq__0
```

Statistics for this query are the following:

```
Table 'Address'. Scan count 2, logical reads 55305, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 492, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
CPU time = 1687 ms,  elapsed time = 75987 ms.
```

If we execute the same query without the [C%] columns. (Like it should)
We get the following statistics

```
Table 'Address'. Scan count 2, logical reads 55305, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 6, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
CPU time = 844 ms,  elapsed time = 25446 ms.
```

What we notice is the read aheads are the big difference and the cpu, elapsed time.

The client statistics look like this.
[image: client statistics]

**Is there a way we can disable these extra columns being generated?** So we don't have the IO overhead of [C%] columns which are NVARCHARs

*The execution plan of the query is not an issue. We do a clustered index seek on the table. Datatypes of the parameter match on the columns, to prevent implicit casting in SQL*

Comment: I checked this issue on my side, I found I could encounter the same issue as you provided. Per my search and test, I did not find any option to disable this feature, but I would dig into this issue tomorrow.

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT any update about this?

Comment: I just found adding `$select` like this `https://{app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/{table-name}?$select=id,text` for retrieving expected data columns (e.g removing the system properties), but it would still generate the extra columns.

Comment: What is the reason the columns are being generated? Since they contain the same values as the column names. Can you point me in the direction where in the source this happens ?

Comment: AFAIK, the query method in the `TableController` would return `IQueryable<Address>` and the query is normal, so I suspect that there be some code defined in the higher level (e.g.  override [ApiControllerActionInvoker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.apicontrolleractioninvoker(v=vs.118).aspx) etc.) to add extra columns and execute the query. But I did not find any specific code under the packages like `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.*` for now.